# Onboard Mobo graphics Not Displaying

Tags: motherboard, graphics, amd-ryzen

I've just finished putting together a new PC build:

- Mobo: MSI b550 gaming plus
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700

There's no GPU at this point but will be eventually, however, in the meantime I'd like to use my new PC.

When I boot it up, everything seems to be running, rgb is going, fans are all working but my monitor is faced with

> no signal

After some research everyone seems to say you have to enable this via bios but... How can I if I can't display the bios? I've tried flashing bios via the button on mobo and still nada.

How do I get onboard graphics to work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need at least a discrete GPU to be able to use that R7-3700

Comment: @tamalesrancheros ahhh i see :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Ryzen 7 CPUs require a discrete graphics card. You cannot use the ryzen 3700X without a graphics card as it has no integrated graphics. You will need to purchase a graphics card for using the processor.

Comment: I would never expect the cpu to have the graphics, I was hoping the mobo would do that leaving the cpu as a cpu?

Comment: @ZeusIsLoose There was a time when some motherboard included an iGPU in the chipset. That time is long gone.

Comment: @ChanganAuto damn :/